# List Output Issue

Tags: python

that might be a silly question but I am having a hard time trying to understand the output of this code. Could anyone help me understand why the output is always '1', no matter what is the digit inside the brackets in the print() function? Thank you so much.

```
my_list = [3, 1,-2]
print(my_list[my_list[-1]])
```

Comment: "No matter"?! `my_list[my_list[0]]` is an `IndexError`…

Comment: Your code returns 1 because `my_list[-1]` is actually the list's last element (-2), and then `my_list[-2]` returns the second to last element, which is 1.

Comment: Go through list indexing `my_list[-1]` return -2 `my_list[-2]` returns 1

Comment: `my_list[-1]` is the last element of `my_list`, that is, -2.  `my_list[-2]` is the second-last element of `my_list[`, that is, 1. Your statement *no matter what is the digit inside the brackets* is overgeneralizing. The possible values are -1, -2, 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_list = [3, 1,-2] 
print(my_list[my_list[-1]])
```

`my_list[-1]` - this statement means take the element from the end of the list, here -2 will be taken.

`my_list[my_list[-1]]` - so here it will by `my_list[-2]` ie 2nd element from the end of the list.

Refer more about negative indexing in python

Answer (score 0):

Because you are asking the value of my_list in posizion -1, and it is -2.... the your code now is:

```
my_list = [3, 1,-2] 
print(my_list[my_list[-1]])
```

my_list[-1] = -2....

```
my_list = [3, 1,-2] 
print(my_list[-2])
```

my_list[-2] = 1. 1 is every time your result